# asp.net mvc - When application published to IIS the controller action returns 404

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an application that was debuging and running locally just fine. When I published it to IIS, the action on the controller is no longer found.

It returns 
`http://server/home/Table2?ids=122026000&ids=123201000&ids=122627000&ids=121514000&ids=123187000 404 (Not Found)`

I am using a JQuery AJAX function to pass IDS to the action that then returns a partial view with the model constructed from the IDS appropriately.

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Table2(string[] ids)
    {

        (......) //query database and build model 

        return PartialView("_Partial", Model);
    }
}
```

**AJAX**

```
var submitAgmtIds = function submitAgmtIds(ids) {

        $.get('Home/Table2', $.param({ ids: ids }, true), function (partialView) {
            $("#av-row-2").html(partialView);
        });

        expandTable();

    }
```

**ROUTE**
These where kept as the default...

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

"ids" is an array such that `var array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Again this worked fine in debug but returns a 404 now that it is on a web server.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get this to work by hard coding my application name into the ajax call such that `{application name}/Home/Table`.. This works as expected. How can I dynamically do this so it will work if the application is deployed under another name?

Comment: see edit.. They where kept as the defaults when the project is built.

Comment: Its in the home controller

Comment: What is the URL of the page where your AJAX call is happening from?

Comment: What version of IIS and is it running in classic mode?

Comment: IIS 7.5... I believe it is running in integrated mode

Comment: Can you reach the site at all .? 
meaning not just this resource

Comment: Yes, I can reach the site and the app functions as normal. It only fails when I need to retrieve something back from the server.

Comment: I am making the ajax call from the page `{server name}/{application name}` The JQuery is then interpreting my get request to `http://{server name}/Home/Table2` I'm suspecting  the fact it doesn't have the application name in the URL is the source of the problem.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by hard coding my application name into the ajax call such that `{application name}/Home/Table`.. This works as expected. How can I dynamically do this so it will work if the application is deployed under another name?

Comment: Use `$.get('/Home/Table2',...` (leading forward slash) or better ` `$.get('@Url.Action("Table2","Home")',...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you may try to change this line :`$.get('Home/Table2', $.param({ ids: ids }, true), function (partialView)`  to like this: `$.get('../Home/Table2', $.param({ ids: ids }, true), function (partialView)`.

**Note:** putting the two dot and  forward slash ../ in front of the home, will solve your problem.

**your Changed ajax code:**

```
var submitAgmtIds = function submitAgmtIds(ids) {

        $.get('../Home/Table2', $.param({ ids: ids }, true), function (partialView) {
            $("#av-row-2").html(partialView);
        });

        expandTable();

    }
```

Hope the above the information was useful , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik